# not seeing anything on screen after I select PopOS from grub menu - just blank until PopOS shows up

Tags: grub, pop-os

I have a laptop that is configured to boot either from Pop-OS or Windows 10.  When I select Pop-OS there will be a series of checks and loadings that show on screen followed by a green "OK".
On my desktop, also configured for Pop-OS and Windows, this series of checks and loadings does not show - just a blank screen until Pop-OS is on screen business as usual.
If I hit F9 anytime after I select PopOS from the grub menu, then this series will scroll across my screen.
Is there anything in /etc/default/grub that I can change to make it show up?

Comment: PopOS normally uses SystemD boot not grub. Did you install using grub? Are both installs in UEFI boot mode?

Comment: Pretty sure both are UEFI.

Comment: Checking my list of things to do when I installed Pop OS - 1.  Download PopOS  2.  Create bootable USB drive  3.  Shrink Windows partition.  4.  Create PopOS partition.  5.  Install PopOS  6.  Configure GRUB

Comment: If using grub you can change quiet splash on linux line. Details: Changed from quiet splash to noplymouth,https://askubuntu.com/questions/1284302/is-it-possible-to-make-ubuntu-20-04-boot-faster  if SystemD not sure where similar setting may be.

Comment: That worked. Thank you very much.